# BufferHow to get STDIN line color with JAVA using BufferedReader

Tags: java, ffmpeg, bufferedreader, java-process-runtime

Im run FFplay process in my JAVA application and read his logs with BufferedReader.
I want to parse the logs to determine errors.
So I want to read the color for each line.
red for errors..
bufferedReader.readline() return the content, no any color code.

Please advise.

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -loglevel level+info`. It will add the log level to the log.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I need info level because im parsing more values out of errros...I need all logs..so im using ׳-loglevel info׳

Comment: The point is to use `level+info` instead of `info`. It tells it that the level it needs is info but **to add the level string to the logs**. Try it!

Comment: Oh you meant literally  level+info, GREAT!

Comment: @RealSkeptic Please write this as answer so I can mark it as resolved, tnx again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ffmpeg and its associated tools emits color codes only when it detects that stderr goes to a terminal that supports color codes. Although this can be overridden by an environment variable, parsing arcane escape codes is not recommended.

Instead, according to the [FFMpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options), you may prefix the log level as a string to the output, by using a *flag* in the `-loglevel` parameter. There are several documented flags, and the applicable one is `level`.

So if you had a log level set with `-loglevel info`, you can change this to `-loglevel level+info`. If you didn't have a log level at all, you can use `-loglevel +level`.

Now the output log messages will be prefixed with `[error]` when the level is error. This works in all ffmpeg tools, including `ffplay`.

Comment: Its working on my Macbook with ffplay version 4.2.2 but it is NOT WORKING in my Ubuntu with ffplay version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: I got 'Invalid loglevel "level+info"'